Mime Type for MS Excel XLSX in VertexAI API
I can successfully process Microsoft Excel XLSX files via the WebUI on GCP (https://console.cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative/multimodal/create/text).
I can also successfully programmatically pass PDFs and TXT files into GCP VertexAI (with mime types "application/pdf" and "text/pain" respectively.)
  user_prompt_content = Content(
  role="user",
  parts=[
      Part.from_text(prompt),
      Part.from_uri(gcp_cloud_object_ref, mime_type=obj_mime_type)
  ],

)
However, I cannot process XLSX files programmatically, presumably due to the mime type. When I try "application/pdf" I get

InvalidArgument: 400 The document has no pages.

When I try "text/plain" I get

InvalidArgument: 400 Request contains an invalid argument.

GCP docs do not list the correct mime type to use (https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/model-reference/inference) but I tried the usual type unsuccessfully

application/vnd.ms-excel
xlsm application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12
xlsx application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

The docs and error might suggest that XLSX cannot be processed, but then how is the web-ui achieving this? Can I replicate the same functionality as the web-ui programmatically?
